# How to align Radio buttons at left side in Touch Sencha?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch

Is there any solution for align these radio buttons at left side.
here is sample sencha touch code you can run it on [sencha fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOFIm.png)

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
      var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            name : 'color',
            value: 'red',
            label: 'Red',
            labelAlign: 'right',
            checked: true
        },
        {
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            name : 'color',
            value: 'green',
            label: 'Green'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            name : 'color',
            value: 'blue',
            label: 'Blue'
        }
    ]
});
    }
});
```

here is 3 radio buttons. First one I am trying to set at left side and want to set it's label align at right side. I did that by using config option  `labelAlign: 'right'` But you can see in design, there is label getting set at right side, but component not getting sets at left side. I don't know why this adding padding at the left side. I tried lots stuffs for this but unable to resolve this issue. have you any suggestion/solution on this issue?

[image]

you can see above image there is space after I setting label as right. That space I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML/CSS source says reason for radio box on right is:

```
.x-field.x-body-align-end > * > .x-body-el {
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

The ExtJS Field source says `body-align-...` class is set here:

```
updateBodyAlign: function(bodyAlign, oldBodyAlign) {
    var element = this.element;

    if (oldBodyAlign) {
        element.removeCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'body-align-' + oldBodyAlign);
    }

    if (bodyAlign) {
        element.addCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'body-align-' + bodyAlign);
    }
},
```

So I tried in fiddle:

```
bodyAlign: 'start',
```

and it works.

Comment: Can you explain more? How you did that?

Comment: [Inspect element in Chrome](https://i.imgur.com/gZOMvb0.png), and then I stepped through the classes in the [radio's class hierarchy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.field.Radio.html) one by one and searched through the source code files for occurrences of the bits of the class name.